# Correct article to use before noun + preposition

Tags: indefinite-article, zero-article

May you give me an explanation on what's the difference if I say these following sentences :

Cream is a part of milk that contains fat.

And

Cream is the part of milk that contains fat.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: welcome!

> Cream is a part of milk that contains fat.

'a part' relates to one part among others. There is no relation to the attributes of the other parts.

> Cream is the part of milk that contains fat.

'the part' relates to one specific part among others. For me it sounds that none of the other ingredients contains fat after the usage of 'the'.

*Note: I am no native speaker nor an expert - I am just trying to help.*

Answer (score 0):

> *Cream is **a** part...* means there are many parts of milk that contain fat and cream is one of them.

> *Cream is **the** part...* means there are many parts of milk but cream is the *only* part that contains fat.